# Oficial Deployment of laravel in aws

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, homestead

I am programming laravel projects on my local computer in Homestead

I am looking for the official guide or manual or tutorial to configure my virtual machine in aws or any other cloud computing service

I want to efficiently replicate the local Homestead environment in some cloud computing service.

Comment: use can use Laravel Forge

Answer (score 1):

Homestead is for local dev enviroments. If you want to deploy on aws, you need an ec2, and then put a nginx, caddy, apache or another server with php support on it. 
You can easily create docker containers with docker-compose installed on your ec2 and then installing laradock for easily configuring and managing the laravel production enviroment needs.

Comment: I confirm

YES, Homestead is a local development environment

The production environment and the local development environment must be the same, to work under the same conditions

I need a step by step how to configure ngnix, php and mysql in the same way as in my local Homestead environment.

The two environments must be the same.

Comment: the production enviroment and the development enviroment is not the same and must be different, you can use a linux ec2 based machine or a windows ec2 based machine, then on windows or linux you can continue installing your production enviroment, i recommend linux, and then copy your code to your machine,, then install clone, configure and start laradock container aside your code.